# Pre-loading audio in HTML5 takes time

Tags: css, html, audio

When you do the Konami code on my [website](https://christopherkade.com) (Up, Up, Down, Down, Left, Right, Left, Right, b, a) a Star Wars Crawl screen appears.

Everything works fine but the music is not synced to the (extremely important) logo appearance. Here's how I load my audio files:

```
<audio preload="auto" autoplay>
  <source src="https://s.cdpn.io/1202/Star_Wars_original_opening_crawl_1977.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="https://s.cdpn.io/1202/Star_Wars_original_opening_crawl_1977.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

And here's how I time my logo appearance (after the intro phrase):

```
.logo
   animation: logo 9s ease-out 9s
```

(It is then scaled with a `keyframes`)

The audio takes a small while to load which in terms ruins the whole thing, how may I solve this problem? Would it help if the audio files were local?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that I had the answer, having the music locally makes it load very efficiently.

```
<audio preload="auto" autoplay>
  <source src="./../../assets/audio/Star_Wars_original_opening_crawl_1977.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```